# Can't change text in JTextArea in Java

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea, jfilechooser

I created a class that extends another class, so that I can get the JTextArea from the main class. I'm not getting any errors for some reason. When I get the text of the JTextArea it is the text that I changed it to, but it isn't showing up on the JTextArea. I am trying to open a txt file and get the text from the file and put it on the JTextArea. Can anyone please make any suggestions why this might not work?

```
 public JMenuItem open(){
        open.addActionListener (new ActionListener (){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                jta.setText("");
                fileChooser=new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a file...");
                int response=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                if(response==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    String filePath=fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
                    try{
                        File userFile=new File(filePath);
                        Scanner scan=new Scanner(userFile);
                        String text="";
                        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                            text+=scan.nextLine();
                            jta.replaceSelection(text);
                        }
                    }catch (IOException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('O', KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        return open;
    }
```

This ^^^ is used like so:

```
public class FileMenu extends MenuBar{
    private JMenu file=new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem New= new JMenuItem("New");
    JMenuItem open= new JMenuItem("Open file...");
    JMenuItem save= new JMenuItem("Save");
    JMenuItem saveAs= new JMenuItem("Save As...");
    JMenuItem close= new JMenuItem("Exit");
    public JFileChooser fileChooser;
    FileActions fileActions;

    public FileMenu(){

    }

    public JMenu menu(){
        fileActions=new FileActions();
        file.add(fileActions.newWindow());
        file.add(fileActions.open());
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(save);
        file.add(saveAs);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(close);

        save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('S', KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        saveAs.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('E', KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        close.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('Q', KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));

        mb.add(file);
        return file;
    }
}
```

This is where the JTextArea is created:

```
public class Frame {
    static final String title="Simple Text Editor";
    static final int width=650;
    static final int height=700;
    public JFrame frame=new JFrame(title);
    public JTextArea jta=new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(jta);

    public void create(){
        //JFrame
        frame.setSize(width,height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // JMenuBar
        MenuBar menuBar=new MenuBar();
        frame.add(menuBar.menuBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        jta.setText("Well this works...");
        // JTextArea
        jta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a **small** minimal sample code showing the problem?

Comment: Look at the middle script in the open function. In the while loop I am trying to take the text from the file and trying to put it on the JTextArea

Comment: *"Look at the middle script.."*  Post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure there is no better option to read the file than the Event Dispatch Thread? Probably reading in a separate thread and updating the text with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...})` would  solve the update problem.

Comment: No, not an uncompilable code snippet, a ***[MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to populate the text area with the content of a text file. But to do that you read every line of the text file and do

```
jta.replaceSelection(text);
```

But as its name and javadoc indicates, `replaceSelection()` replaces the text selected by the user in the text area. What you simply want is to clear the text area and append the text to the text area:

```
jta.setText(""); // clear
while (scan.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    jta.append(line);
    jta.append("\n");
}
```

Or, easier:

```
jta.read(new FileReader(userFile, null);
```

which will read everything from the file for you and populate the text area with its content.